# Fixing too long comment lines in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm looking for a convenient way to fix comments where line lengths exceed a certain number of characters in Vim. I'm fine with doing this manually with code, especially since it's not that frequent, plus refactoring long lines is often language, or even code-style dependent, but with comments this is pure drudgery.

What happens is I often spot some issue in a comment, tweak one or two words and the line spills out of the, say, 80 character limit. I move the last word to the next line and then the next line spills, and so on. Does anyone know a way to do this automatically in Vim?

Comment: I think it's just set textwidth=80, then gq<motion> to reformat.

Comment: Oh my, I can't believe it's that simple, thanks!

Comment: @DeepYellow but it seems it only *carriage-returns* when you write at the end of the line, doesn't it? If you add text at the beginning, it doesn't move exceeding text to the next line. Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I've noticed that at first too, but it should work if you pick a motion which includes that next line. I've found that visual-selecting the whole comment block and running gq works best for me.

Comment: Tomek is right, or do gqj to format with the next line.  I usually just just repeat that a few times.

Comment: @nadirs If you want it to wrap when you write *anywhere*, include `a` in `formatoptions`. Also be sure that it contains `c` to work in comments and see `:h fo-table` for other useful characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend putting the following into your vimrc if this is a regular issue:

```
nnoremap <leader>f gqip
```

This maps the leader f shortcut (f is for "format") to format the comment (considered a paragraph after setting some formatoption flags) with gq which formats the comment to be the width of the currently set `textwidth` or `tw` option. You should set textwidth in your .vimrc with `textwidth=80`.

Formatoptions is the other thing you should fiddle with, specifically in your case by adding the `acq` flags with `formatoptions+=acq`. Be careful to remove the `t` flag with `formatoptions-=t` because that will automatically wrap all of your code, not just recognized comments. After doing all this you should be able to hit f and format inside only the comment, irrespective of whether is is surrounded by blank lines.

Here is the relevant info on formatoptions so you can make your own choices.

```
t       Auto-wrap text using textwidth

c       Auto-wrap comments using textwidth, inserting the current comment
    leader automatically.

r       Automatically insert the current comment leader after hitting
    <Enter> in Insert mode.

o       Automatically insert the current comment leader after hitting 'o' or
    'O' in Normal mode.

q       Allow formatting of comments with "gq".
    Note that formatting will not change blank lines or lines containing
    only the comment leader.  A new paragraph starts after such a line,
    or when the comment leader changes.

w       Trailing white space indicates a paragraph continues in the next line.
    A line that ends in a non-white character ends a paragraph.

a       Automatic formatting of paragraphs.  Every time text is inserted or
    deleted the paragraph will be reformatted.  See |auto-format|.
    When the 'c' flag is present this only happens for recognized
    comments.
```